# Твит-лента на сайт

Tags: twitter

Здравствуйте, где найти стандартную твит ленту на сайт, как тут:

[image]

Обыскался уже на твиттере, не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел: [Ресурсы › Виджеты](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets).